# How to Compress UIIMage Using TinyPNG Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, http

I have a request in Swift 5 that is trying to make a call to tinify.com. It is supposed to give me back a URL to a compressed image. I am currently getting this error in the print field:

```
{"error":"Not found","message":"This endpoint does not exist."}
```

[TinyPNG.com API Reference](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference)

Code:

```
let string = "https://api.tinify.com/shrink"
let url = NSURL(string: string)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("fakeAPIKey1234", forHTTPHeaderField: "user api")
request.addValue("/dev/stdout", forHTTPHeaderField: "dump-header")
request.addValue("\(String(describing: self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!))", forHTTPHeaderField: "data-binary")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    guard error == nil else { print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }

    if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Grab Image from this url: \(str)")
    }
}
```

**Note: fakeAPIKey1234 is not actually the string I'm using. Also I'm sure there is more wrong with my code than this little issue.**

Comment: Going by the doumentation I see that HTTP method is POST. You are using GET. Could that be an issue?

Comment: OK I will try this @Rishab Thanks

Comment: `String(describing: Data())` doesn't magically give you the encoded binary; neither does it produce any pointer to a file locally.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? @Hunter